# Excel - Conditional Formatting - Apply format if the % sum of a given set in a table is 100%

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have this table.

[image: Table]

I want the **Percentage** rows to show in red when the sum of them for a given week doesn't total 100% (visual queue for people to fill their time to 100%). Do the same for every next week.

I am using this formula in Conditional Formatting,
*=SUMIF($B$2:$B$11,UNIQUE($B$2:$B$11),$D$2:$D$11)<>100%*

The problem is, that as soon as one week's percentage totals 100%, the format dissapears for the entire table. Not sure if the problem is the formula or the Applies to field that equals *=$D$2:$D$11*

Can you guys help?

Thanks!

Comment: you might have to wrap the sumif part with round. As it is now there may be rounding at the 9th decimal place which would cause issues...

Answer (score 1):

don't change the field of "=$D$2:$D$11" in Applies to, try this formula.

=SUMIF($B$2:$B$11,$B2,$D$2:$D$11)<>100%

Comment: Hi, if you have a chance to check this issue, please check whether my answer is helpful.